# Отслеживание нажатия ПКМ

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Мне нужно отслеживать нажатия ПКМ, причем, не по форме или какому-то контроллеру, а просто нажатие мышки. Есть какое-то событие для этого? Я ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Решил так:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            //код
        }
    }
```

Я искал отдельное событие, но это делалось через MouseDown с проверкой кнопки в нём.

Comment: Так это именно по форме и есть